# Which requirements are necssary to RWRMTN app load datasets in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I am trying to use the app RWRMTN in cytoscape, but seems that my computer can't load the data set. The process is using more than 90% of the RAM (16GB; amd ryzen 5 3.2ghz 6 core processor) and is going for 4 days now. I am new in this, is this normal? Is my computer not enough to use this app?

Thank you for your help,
Ana

Answer (score 0):

Which data set is it having problems loading?  I was able to load the TargetScan data set and the miR2Disease data set without any issues, although I do have a machine with 32Gb of RAM.  Could it be that it was trying to create a view?  That network has 500,000 edges, so creating a view would be somewhat intensive.

P.S.  Loading the datasets took about 8 seconds on my machine, so something is definitely wrong.  What version of Cytoscape are you running?

Comment: Thank you. I have the version 3.8.0. I just clicked load datasets. You can tell me what I should do differently? How to avoid the program to try creating a view.